# twitter api returns incorrect timestamp

Tags: twitter

I noticed that something seems wrong with the timestamp returned by the twitter api. I am looking at Obama's tweet announcing his behind the scenes video.

https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/557613911835672576

This tweet was posted at 11AM EST. Now I know the API returns tweets in UTC but my return value for *created_at* is:

Tue Jan 20 19:01:31 +0000 2015
Watch: President Obama gives a behind-the-scenes look into tonight's #SOTU address. http://t.co/bCW5Kt2Jb4

So the UTC to EST conversion typically says subtract 5 hours but that would place the tweet at 2pm EST when on Twitter proper it says 11 am...

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Slightly confused - when I look at the tweet, and the API, it shows as 19:01.  Where are you seeing 11:00?

Comment: It is this status: https://twitter.com/BarackObama/status/557613911835672576 -- which the API returns as 2pm for EST (API returns 19.01 so minus 5 HRS would be 14.01)... But when I open that status up on my desktop on a computer located in EST it shows 11am. I believe it might be a bug within twitter itself... Also investigated it here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/utc-offset-incorrect/31275